# How to save video in documents folder then upload to server

Tags: iphone, ipad, video-capture

I am recording video from the iPad app and I want that video may be saved in documents folder or directly we may upload that to server. I have store audio file in documents but how to save a video file. I am using following code for recording video.

```
  UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
  picker.delegate = self;

  if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
  {
    NSArray *mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString*)kUTTypeMovie];
    picker.mediaTypes = mediaTypes ;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    picker.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModeVideo ;

    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:NO];

    [picker release];
}
  else
    {

UIAlertView *alt=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@" Camera Facility is not available with this Device" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alt show];
    [alt release];
    }
```

Comment: @Popeye you can see that question is how to record video but problem is not saving that is why i have asked this question so there is no need to -1 for this

Comment: The answer you have accepted tells you how to save and record. You should have not asked another question that is exactly the same that is why I have given you -1. If it doesn't work than you shouldn't have accepted the answer as this will mislead other users.

Comment: @Popeye Ok i got this

Comment: To be honest as well you have a question about posting data to server as well. It isn't a duplicate but you could put two and two together to get your answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this, I've stored it with current Date-Time ::

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController*)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary*)info
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
    NSString *type = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];

    if ([type isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeVideo] || [type isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie])
    {
        videoURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];

        NSLog(@"found a video");

        // Code To give Name to video and store to DocumentDirectory //

        videoData = [[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:videoURL] retain];
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

        NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
        [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy||HH:mm:SS"];
        NSDate *now = [[[NSDate alloc] init] autorelease];
        theDate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:now];

        NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Default Album"];

        if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataPath])
           [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:nil];

        NSString *videopath= [[[NSString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.mov",documentsDirectory,theDate]] autorelease];

        BOOL success = [videoData writeToFile:videopath atomically:NO];

        NSLog(@"Successs:::: %@", success ? @"YES" : @"NO");
        NSLog(@"video path --> %@",videopath);
    }
}
```

Video Uploading ::

**`videoData`** is getting from `videoData = [[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:videoURL] retain];`

```
- (void)uploadVideo
{
    NSData *imageData = videoData;

    NSString *urlString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", UploadVideoService];
    NSLog(@"url=== %@", urlString);

    request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

    /*  body of the post */

    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    //Video Name with Date-Time
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd-hh:mm:ssa"];
    NSString *currDate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"video-%@.mov\"\r\n", currDate];
    NSLog(@"String name::  %@",str);

    [dateFormat release];

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:str] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [request setHTTPBody:body];

    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"result from webservice:::--> %@", returnString);

    [returnString release];
}
```

Hope, it'll help you.

Thanks.

Comment: this method will call automatically

Comment: When you click 'Use' button, it'll call automatically. I've just put code for saving video in doc dir inside this method.

Comment: and when i want to upload this to server then how will i access this path

Comment: and what is the data type of video url i have to decalre variable it is giving eror

Comment: @DeveloperIOS like this answer has been given on the link provided. If this resolves your issue you should have accepted this one on the other question not asked it again.

Comment: @DeveloperIOS: I've edited code for that. please check it

Comment: @iManan I am assuming you aren't using ARC?

Comment: @Popeye: yea. It's non-ARC

Comment: @iManan video type of video url and what to give in UploadVideoServie

Comment: @iManan not that it matters to much you have a small memory leak were you never release some objects in your code. +1 though as except for that its a good answer.

Comment: @DeveloperIOS: UploadVideoService is web-service url where you want to upload video. and type can be anything as I took ".mov"

Comment: @iManan video is not uploading to server it returens string temporary file not uploaded

Comment: @DeveloperIOS: then check your server side settings as well as permissions.

Comment: <?php
$uploaddir = 'pro/';
$file = basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . $file;

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
   echo "OK";
} else {
echo "ERROR";
}
?>

Comment: this is my web service code

Comment: @iManan this same web service for audio file is working fine

Comment: @DeveloperIOS: I think, there is an issue regarding php web-service.

Comment: so any idea hot to solve this

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26526/discussion-between-developer-ios-and-imanan)

Comment: @iManan what is "theDate" ? i am new in ios so plz guide me.

Comment: @AppleMap: 'theDate' is variable that storing Current Timestamp. I'm appending this current timestamp with my videoName. So it'll always save in 'Video_CURR_DATE_TIME.mov' format. So will get exact date & time too while fetching all video records.

Comment: @iManan: Hi Manan, I tried your code but it's sending me blank response and even my mp4 file is also not uploading on server. I am not getting why it's not working for me.Can you please help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

Once try like this,

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)imagePicker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info 
{

    NSURL *videoUrl = (NSURL *)[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL]; 

    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"hh:mm:ss";
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];

    NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:videoUrl];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *savedvedioPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:now]]];
    savedvedioPath  = [savedvedioPath stringByAppendingFormat:@".mp4"];
    [videoData writeToFile:savedvedioPath atomically:NO];

    //here is the method to upload onto server
    [self Upload_server:savedvedioPath];

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

now define your method to upload vedio like,

```
-(void)Upload_server:(NSString*)file_path {

  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"YOUR_URL_TO_UPLOAD"];
  ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
  [request setUseKeychainPersistence:YES];
  [request addFile:file_path forKey:@"YOUR_KEY"];

//insted of in above line you can also use [request setData:vedioData withFileName:@"your_file_name" andContentType:@"video/mp4" forKey:@"YOUR_KEY"] by Sending  vedioData of type NSData as another perameter to this method.

[request setDelegate:self];
[request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(uploadRequestFinished:)];
[request setDidFailSelector:@selector(uploadRequestFailed:)];
[request startAsynchronous];

}
```

now implement ASIFormDataRequest delegatemethods like,

```
- (void)uploadRequestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request{ 

   NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
  //do something after sucessful upload

}

- (void)uploadRequestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request{

  NSLog(@" Error - Statistics file upload failed: \"%@\"",[[request error] localizedDescription]); 

  }
```

Here i took ASIFormDataRequest to upload on to server.hope it will hepls you..

Answer (score 0):

```
//for video..
#import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <MediaPlayer/Mediaplayer.h>

#import <CoreMedia/CoreMedia.h>



UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;

    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
    {
        NSArray *mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString*)kUTTypeMovie];
        picker.mediaTypes = mediaTypes ;
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        picker.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModeVideo ;

        [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:NO];

        [picker release];
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alt=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@" Camera Facility is not available with this Device" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alt show];
        [alt release];
    }
```

**for saving into Document folder & it also save in photo Library**

```
NSArray* paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString* documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];


        //for video
        NSURL *videoURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
        NSLog(@"video url-%@",videoURL);

        NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:videoURL];

        NSString * videoName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"student_%d_%d.mp4",stud_id,imgVidID];

        videoPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:videoName];

        NSLog(@"video path-%@",videoPath);

        [videoData writeToFile:videoPath atomically:YES];

        NSString *sourcePath = [[info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL"]relativePath];

        UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(sourcePath,nil,nil,nil);
}
```

Comment: Whilst I don't mind links as answers others don't like them. So I will give you a quick warning if it is just a link please add as comment.

Comment: yes, you will get the answer of your problem. This is a stackOverflow's link nothing else.

Comment: You shouldn't be placing a link as an answer they belong in comments. If you do provide a link as an answer it should really be joined by a summary of what you are pointing them too.

Comment: Please see here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Comment: Copying someone else's work like you have done from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15475315/how-to-record-a-video-clip-in-ipad-app-and-store-it-in-documents-folder is also not a good idea. Your taking credit for someone else's work.

Comment: If u see that link, You will find that Its not someone else's answer. It was mine.

Comment: In that case you should be advising them that there question is an exact duplicate of that question. And telling them they would be able to find there answer in that link. And that is why I now go back to my original comment links should provided as comments not answers.