# Filter the contents of the Photo Gallery from my app

Tags: ios, video, recorder

I have an application that will take care of recording video using UIImagePickerController object and videos are saved in the shared library of IOS.
I have only one problem.
If you record video from an external application to my application, unfortunately I can see both the videos recorded with my application is the video recorded by the other application.
Is there a way to make the filter of assets not recorded with my application?
Thank you,
Vincenzo

Comment: Initially my application saved in the My Documents folder, but then I was prompted to make a backup folder within the video of IOS.

Answer (score 1):

Save video to apps document folder and while using, pick it from the same location.

Refer [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15518925/how-to-save-video-in-documents-folder-then-upload-to-server) to save video in documents folder.
But your other apps are unable to access those and deleting app deletes captured videos too.